# The Curious Case Of Python Scripts And Constantly Running Fan

Tags: python, fancontrol

My question concerns using python scripts (cough) in an Ubuntu 17.10 terminal. I noticed on running them that the fan on my laptop kicks right in and keeps going until I close the terminal. Should that be happening? My laptop's specs are 256 Gig SSD 8 GB RAM Intel® Core™ i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 Any ideas or suggestions on this would be very welcome. MR

Comment: If your "python scripts (cough)" are CPU-intensive, your CPUs may heat up. When your CPUs get too hot, the fan, probably thermostatically controlled, turns on to circulate air and remove heat.

Comment: All makes perfect sense, apart from similar 'actions' taken on a Window's 8.1 laptop with less impressive specs, running Kali Linux in VBox, yet the fan hardly kicked in..Hmmm right?

Comment: Try other resource-intensive tasks, and see if the fan kicks in then as well. If you feel like it's not supposed to do that, check if there are any fan-related settings in the firmware or any updates for the firmware.